# XSLT to CSV - How to control the order of the same element with different attribute values?

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am quite a newbie to XSLT and I need to figure out how to retrieve repeating elements from a XML file in a specific order based on their attribute value to a CSV file. My result document is a CSV file that I ultimately need to import its content to SQL Server tables. Therefore, the order of the retrieved elements within the CSV file does matter as they need to match the table columns defined as headers.

My problem occurs with the *Project Content_Detail* element that exists in different languages and can appear in any order in the XML source. I only need to extract the German version with the *Title, Goal* element first, followed by the English version elements.

I use SSIS with MS Visual Studio 2019 to transform my XML to a CSV file. MS Visual Studio supports only XSLT 1.0.

Here is my XML file (EDITED):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dta:Projects xmlns:dta="http://domain.test/dta">
  <dta:Project>
    <dta:Core-Basis>
      <dta:Goal>1672</dta:Goal>
    </dta:Core-Basis>
    <dta:Basisinfo>
      <dta:Content>
        <dta:Content_Detail Lang="de">
          <dta:Title>Wirtschaft</dta:Title>
          <dta:Aim>Steigerung</dta:Aim>
        </dta:Content_Detail>
        <dta:Content_Detail Lang="en">
          <dta:Title>Economy</dta:Title>
        </dta:Content_Detail>
      </dta:Content>
    </dta:Basisinfo>
  </dta:Project>
  <dta:Project >
    <dta:Core-Basis>
      <dta:Goal>2035</dta:Goal>
    </dta:Core-Basis>
    <dta:Basisinfo>
      <dta:Content>
        <dta:Content_Detail Lang="en">
          <dta:Title>Environmental Protection</dta:Title>
          <dta:Aim>Facilitation</dta:Aim>
        </dta:Content_Detail>
        <dta:Content_Detail Lang="de">
          <dta:Title>Naturschutz</dta:Title>
        </dta:Content_Detail>
      </dta:Content>
    </dta:Basisinfo>
  </dta:Project >
</dta:Projects>
```

This is my XSLT file (EDITED). I tried to add numerous order and sort arguments to the xsl:if block but I couldn’t come up with a working solution yet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:dta="http://domain.test/dta" exclude-result-prefixes="dta">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>DTA_Goal;DTA_Title_de;DTA_Aim_de;DTA_Title_en;DTA_Aim_en;&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="find_content"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()|@*" mode="find_content"/>
    <xsl:template match="dta:Project" mode="find_content">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(dta:Core-Basis/dta:Goal,';')"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="find_content"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="dta:Content_Detail" mode="find_content">
        <xsl:if test="@Lang='de'">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(dta:Title,';')"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(dta:Aim,';')"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="@Lang='en'">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(dta:Title,';')"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(dta:Aim,'&#xA;')"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is my CSV output so far, not sorting the Content_detail based on their language value attribute:

```
DTA_Goal;DTA_Title_de;DTA_Aim_de;DTA_Title_en;DTA_Aim_en;
1672;Wirtschaft;Steigerung;Economy;
2035;Environmental Protection;Facilitation
Naturschutz;;
```

This is what I need:

```
DTA_Goal; DTA_Title_de; DTA_Aim_de; DTA_Title_en; DTA_Aim_en;
1672;Wirtschaft;Steigerung;Economy;;
2035;Naturschutz;;Environmental Protection;Facilitation;
```

As I am not a professional programmer, any help or comment also on the rest of my code is highly appreciated.

Comment: The stylesheet you have posted does NOT produce the output you show.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: Sorry, that's true. I simplied the code snippets and missed to re-run the code. I changed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your input, one of the `dta:Project` elements has a `dta:Core-Basis` child, while the other has `dta:Core-Basisdaten`. Assuming that's a mistake*, you could produce the needed output simply by:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:dta="http://domain.test/dta">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:template match="/dta:Projects">
    <!-- header -->
    <xsl:text>DTA_Goal;DTA_Title_de;DTA_Aim_de;DTA_Title_en;DTA_Aim_en;&#10;</xsl:text>
    <!-- data -->
    <xsl:for-each select="dta:Project">
        <xsl:value-of select="dta:Core-Basis/dta:Goal"/>
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <!-- de -->
        <xsl:variable name="content-de" select="dta:Basisinfo/dta:Content/dta:Content_Detail[@Lang='de']" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$content-de/dta:Title"/>
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$content-de/dta:Aim"/>
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <!-- en -->
        <xsl:variable name="content-en" select="dta:Basisinfo/dta:Content/dta:Content_Detail[@Lang='en']" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$content-en/dta:Title"/>
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$content-en/dta:Aim"/>
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

(*) If not, change:

```
<xsl:value-of select="dta:Core-Basis/dta:Goal"/>
```

to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="(dta:Core-Basis|dta:Core-Basisdaten)/dta:Goal"/>
```

---

P.S. Not sure why you need the trailing `;` at the end of each line.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick answer @michael.hor257k ! This worked out perfectly and it gives me a good guideline to carry on. As I understand, the for-each loop allows me to define the order of elements retrieved from the XML. It also prevents that random content is thrown out by the processor as it did before when not overriding the built-in rules of the used templates.

Comment: Not exactly. The correct order here is achieved not by the `xsl:for-each` instruction (which BTW is not a "loop") but by explicit listing of each cell in the data row. This ensures that if a node is missing, there will still be an empty cell in the output.